# What is this “Bing Application”?

Tags: bing

I found this today on Bing:[image]
Clicking leads you to `bingsearch://app/search?q=ghhfgfgdgfdgh&FORM=HDRW8P`, which is not any known or sensible protocol and consequently displays as a dead link. What is this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a chance that it's related to the bing app that is on a Windows 8 computer. I've noticed several times that when using bing on a Windows 8 device that is suggests using the app. Although I haven't seen that particular link.

Comment: I’m not using Windows 8.

Comment: This might be the case. See [this](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://www.blogcn.me/archives/tag/bing&prev=/search%3Fq%3DHDRW8P%26hl%3Den%26client%3Dsafari%26tbo%3Dd%26rls%3Den&sa=X&ei=OZ8PUcDSLMXdtAbjwoCoCw&ved=0CDkQ7gEwAQ) (translated) blog post.

Comment: @Alex sorry, but I don’t speak Google Translate.

Comment: @kinokijuf It’s a link to the Windows 8 Bing App, so basically that link opens the Metro Bing App with the search query the user inserted. And probably it was a bug that made it appear even if you are/were not using Windows 8.